Proof of Convergence Rate for Steepest Descent with Exact Line Search
I am trying to understand a theorem about the convergence rate of the steepest descent method with exact line searches. The theorem states:
**Suppose
$:^→$ is twice continuously differentiable, and the iterates generated by the steepest descent method with exact line searches converge to a point $^∗$ where the Hessian matrix $∇^2(^∗)$ is positive definite. Then:
$f(x_{k+1}) - f(x^*) \leq \left( \frac{\lambda_n - \lambda_1}{\lambda_n + \lambda_1} \right)^2 \left[ f(x_k) - f(x^*) \right].$
where $_1≤⋯≤_$ are the eigenvalues of $∇^2(^∗)$**
I am looking for a detailed proof or references that explain why this inequality holds. Specifically, I am trying to understand:
How the eigenvalues $_1$ and $_$  (extreme eigenvalues of the Hessian) determine the rate of convergence.
The role of the positive definiteness of $∇^2(^∗)$ in deriving this bound.
Why the convergence rate depends on the ratio $\frac{\lambda_n - \lambda_1}{\lambda_n + \lambda_1} $
Any help with a rigorous proof, outline, or reference would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
